# Check if mongo document field exists

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I want to check if the field "imageUrl" are inserted from a form into a MongoDb collection.

If it has a value, I want to return the URL, else return false. I'm not used to Mongo, and wonder how I can achieve this. Not every entry have a imageUrl field, but some do. So I need to check if it even exists for every document.

Here's my helper, where I want to have the logic:

```
Template.CatchesList.helpers({
  catches: function () {
    return Catches.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}});
  },

  image: function() {
    if (this.imageURL) // Need proper logic here
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
});
```

And in my template:

```
{{#if image}}
    <td><img width="100" src="{{imageUrl}}"></td>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB has the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator to filter results where the property does not exist in the document. So you can change your query to:

```js
return Catches.find({ "imageUrl": { "$exists": true }}, { "sort": { "date": -1 }});
```

And then only items that have the property will be returned.

If you are only talking about templates, then a simple conditional test on the field returns logically where it is present or not present:

```js
{{#each catches}}
    {{> catch }}
{{/each}}
```

Then:

```js
<template name="catch">
    <tr>
        <!-- other fields -->
        <td>{{#if imageUrl}}<img width="100" src="{{imageUrl}}">{{/if}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Where only the logic contained within `{{#if}}{{/if}}` will actually render.

Comment: But this will only give the documents that have "imageUrl". I also need the ones that don't.

Comment: @FilipBlaauw Sorry, but that did not come across clearly to me. Putting a logical condition in a template based on field presence is easy. See the example

Answer (score 1):

I did this in an app and it worked for me:

```
    Courses.find({owned_by_contract:user_contract._id}).forEach(function(doc){
        var foo = ("your_field_name" in doc) ? doc.course_objective_english.value:"N/A";
    }):
```